# How to send and receive message to the topic of Azure Service bus in Ruby

Tags: ruby, sinatra, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics, azure-servicebus-subscriptions

How to integrate Azure Service Bus in my Ruby Application to send and receive message from a topic?

Comment: Please see if this helps: https://example-code.com/ruby/azureServiceBus.asp.

Comment: @GauravMantri, Thanks for the response, but I wanted to know If we have some ruby gem which is more stable, . In above link its 3rd party library not from ruby community

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: Ok Thankyou so much for your quick response.

Answer (score 1):

​To integrate Azure Service Bus in my Ruby Application to send and receive message from a topic. Please follow the below :

you can install the azure ruby-gem package directly.

```
gem install azure
```

There are two ways you can set up the connections:

1. [via code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-ruby/tree/asm#via-code)
2. [via environment variables](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-ruby/tree/asm#via-environment-variables)

Use the below command to Send a topic message with the message body

```
azure_service_bus.send_topic_message(topic1, "test topic message")
```

And To Receive a message use the below command

```
message = service_bus.receive_subscription_message(topic1.name, subscription.name)
```

Please refer the  [Link to intigrate Azure service bus in your Ruby application](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-ruby/tree/asm#usage)  to fully meet your requirement.

Comment: I guess the gem is kind-of retired (FYI) and the doc says to use Azure REST API directly :| 
So don't use gem, just call REST ? And if one doesn't want to - is there some azure gem fork that's somewhat maintained ?